# How to send Uniswap V3: Positions NFT to another wallet using Node.js

Tags: nft, uniswap, nodejs, ethers.js, uniswapv3

I have the private key for the wallet. How can I send Uniswap V3: Positions NFT (UNI-V3-POS) from this wallet to another wallet using Node.js and ethers.js for example?

Token contract address: [0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88)

Answer (score 1):

You can use safeTransferFrom or transferFrom method.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88#writeContract